# Integration testing with JUnit and Jetty, can't configure url

Tags: java, spring, junit, jetty

I have web application that has been developed and run locally using tomcat, the routing has been configured and everything is working fine. Now, i need to run some integration tests using JUnit and Jetty (the plan is to run those before deploying), for that i'm using following code:

```
server = new Server(2020);
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/projectName");
        webapp.setWar("build/libs/myWarFile.war");
        server.setHandler(webapp);

        server.start();
```

Jetty servers starts up just fine, now the problem is that neither of my links are working. So for example when running project on tomcat, i could access some page like this:

`http://localhost:8080/projectName/page`

But accessing same page from tests returns error code 404:

`http://localhost:2020/projectName/page`

I've poked around a little and found out that the only page that is "working" is `http://localhost:2020/`

It shows the content of my WebContent folder (2 folders META-INF and WEB-INF, neither of which can be accessed). So i feel like i've missed some important part of configuration, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dealt with the issue, it turns out that the code was correct (besides the `setContextPath` which was pointed to me (edited now) ). The issue was in .war file that was generated in gradle (a lot of things were missing for some reason, so it had to be built using Eclipse tools `Export -> WAR File`