# Embedded jetty, access denied

Tags: java, spring, junit, jetty

This is continuation of my previous question [Integration testing with JUnit and Jetty, can't configure url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828954/integration-testing-with-junit-and-jetty-cant-configure-url/17829003) . The code remains pretty much the same, with exception that i added one line to be able to test the whole thing in browser and another one for priority (otherwise the thing doesn't work), so it looks like this:

```
server = new Server(8080);
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/projectName");
webapp.setWar("build/libs/myWarFile.war");
webapp.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
server.setHandler(webapp);
server.start();
server.join();
```

Now when i try to visit one of the pages, i see in console that compilation starts, but at some point it stops with warning:

```
25937 [qtp92265517-17] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
...
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
```

Any ideas what i might be doing wrong? (I haven't set up or messed with any policy files, or changed permissions to anything, project works fine when i run it on tomcat)

Comment: Have you enabled [JSP support](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Embedding_JSP) in Jetty?

Comment: I'm not sure, i'll have a look once i get back to the code, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @SzymonBiliński unfortunately that didn't solve the issue

Comment: The problem may be related to your Ant/Maven/Eclipse/... setup - how exactly are you launching this test? Please post relevant configuration.

Comment: @SzymonBiliński it seems that the issue's been fixed by making some changes in security policy files (unfortunately i can't say what exactly was changed as it was not me who fixed it).